# Lagging Distance on Pirate-Merchant Pursuit Curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> There is a merchant ship travelling with speed $v_m$ upwards parallel to the $y $-axis, starting at the point $(x,y) = (x_0, 0) $. A pirate ship starting at the origin and travelling at speed $v_p$ is trying to intercept the merchant ship by always pointing itself directly at it. If we assume $v_p = v_m $, it is clear that the pirate will never catch the merchant, however, as $t \to \infty $, the pirate ship will also be parallel with the $y$-axis, travelling at some fixed lagging distance, $D $, behind the merchant ship. Find $D $ without explicitly calculating the pursuit curve.

I found this lagging distance to be $D = \frac12 x_0$ by first finding the Pirate's pursuit curve $y(x)$, and then calculating
$$D^2 = (x-x_0)^2+(y(x)-v_m t)^2 = (x-x_0)^2 [1+(\frac{y(x)-v_m t}{x-x_0})^2]$$
By noting that $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x)-v_m t}{x-x_0} $, so that
$$D^2 = (x-x_0)^2 [1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2] $$
Plugging in the known expression for $\frac{dy}{dx} $ and taking the limit as $x \to x_0$ gives the desired result.

However, this is also possible to find *without* knowing the explicit function $y(x) $ (and in turn $\frac{dy}{dx} $). How would I approach this?

**Update:** I have successfully accomplished the task. I will write up an answer shortly for any who are curious

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense.  If the ship is on the $y-axis$, then $x=0$.  Are you saying $x_0=0$? In your second sentence, $x=0$ is not a point, but a line. Perhaps you could rewrite these sentences.  Cheers!

Comment: @MatthewConroy: Thanks for those catches! I have fixed the wording now

Comment: Your statement that "... the pirate ship will be on the y-axis ..." does not follow.  Also, "after an infinite time" does not make sense.

Comment: @MatthewConroy: How about now? All I meant by infinite time was "as $t $ approaches infinity"

Comment: I would say "also be *moving* parallel with the $y$-axis$".  Yes, as $t$ approaches infinity is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} $ and $v_p = v_m = v $
From the arc-length formula, we have
$$\int_0^x \sqrt{1+p(z)}dz = v t = (x-x_0)p(x) + y$$
Taking an $x$ derivative on both sides:
$$\sqrt{1+p(x)} = (x-x_0)p'(x) $$
Separating variables:
$$ \frac{dp}{\sqrt{1+p^2}}= \frac{dx}{x-x_0} $$
Integrating and imposing the condition that $p=0$ at $t=0$, we get
$$\ln(p+\sqrt{1+p^2}) = -\ln(x_0-x) $$
With some algebraic manipulation, we find that
$$p = \frac12 [(1-\frac{x}{x_0})^{-1}+(1-\frac {x}{x_0})] = \frac {2xx_0-x^2}{2x_0 (x_0-x)}$$
Equating this to our original expression for $p(x) $,

$$p = \frac {2xx_0-x^2}{2x_0 (x_0-x)}=\frac{v_mt-y}{x_0-x} $$
Or
$$V_mt-y = \frac{2xx_0-x^2}{2x_0}$$
In the limit that $x \to x_0$, the LHS is precisely the quantity that we are looking for, so:
$$D = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{2xx_0-x^2}{2x_0} = \frac12 x_0$$

Comment: Anyone care to explain the down vote?